# How to take clientside Javascript arrays and POST through a Node.js API into a MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a single webpage that initially has two form inputs, one for a list of names and another for the title of a game. I've written some javascript/jquery that takes the X names and creates X more form inputs meant for each person's specific score. The javascript then creates the following variables upon the clicking of the names/scores form's submit button:

```
gameTitle = Monopoly
users = [Bob, Bill, Jim, Janet]
scores = [100, 110, 90, 80]
positions = [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

I then have a MongoDB schema set up as such:

```
const SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
gameTitle: String,
users: [],
scores: [],
positions: []
});
```

And a Node.js handler as such:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

const Session = require('./Session');

//Post a session to the database
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    Session.create({
        gameTitle : req.body.gameTitle,
        users : req.body.user,
        scores : req.body.score,
        positions : req.body.position
    },
    function (err, session) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding the information to the database");
        res.status(200).send(session);
    });
});
```

Using Postman I can see that posting works when I use this format:

[Postman POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTabH.png)

[Postman GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzl6c.png)

How do I take the created javascript variables and, also upon the clicking of the names/scores form's submit button, POST them through the API and into the MongoDB database?

Apologies if I have missed any important information/code - I haven't fully wrapped my head around how the backend stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have the backend working. What you're missing is the API request. Since your website is not under the same `host:port` than your API server, when doing it from the browser you'll face CORS issues. Let's get to that later:

First, you'll be making an API call. You can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Let's go with fetch here:

```
fetch(url, {
  body: JSON.stringify(yourJavascriptVariablesAsAnObject),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  method: 'POST',
})
  .then(response => {
    // here you can check for status if you want.
    // ...

    return response.json(); // assuming server returns JSON.
  })
  .then(responseBody => {
    // Do something with the server's response body
  });
```

Now for the CORS problem, if your client app is from [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) or at least you're using [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy), you can proxy request really easy.

If you're not, then you need to allow CORS on your nodeJS server. The simplest way is to use a [library](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enable-cors-for-a-single-route).

PS: CORS basically means you can't do requests from a browser to a service living in a different `url:port:, unless that service explicitly says it's ok.

A third option would be putting both UI and server project behind a Web server like Nginx and proxy the requests, but that sounds too complex for what you need.

Comment: Okay, this is new to me, can you confirm a few things? So if I allow the CORS library on the nodeJS API file then I can directly access the API from the website using fetch()? In your example, how do I know what the server returns (i.e. if it's JSON or not), what's the response body, and where can I find out what my specific response body is?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) server returns what you program it to return. For simplicity, using `res.send(session)` sends text, using `res.json(session) sends JSON. 3) Response body is the data the server returns to your client. In your case, the session data. 4) It is the session data. You can open the Chrome Dev Tools and go to the Network tab to see it if you want, after you have made the request

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. One more thing, I thought that fetch() was used for fetching data rather than posting it? Do I need to fetch from the server side?

Comment: fetch() is for making HTTP requests. Generally,  requests for retrieving data are requests using GET method. Requests for posting data are with POST method.

Comment: I'm really scratching my head here. I've pointed the url to server.js, sessionController.js, the folder they're held in... everything returns an error saying 'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.'. I feel like I've pestered you with questions a lot but I can't seem to get this to work. I've put all of the files and their code [here](https://pastebin.com/YQgijj5F) - if you could take a quick look it'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: No no no, that's not how it works. You need to start your server with `node server.js`. It will bind to a port (I assume port 3001). Your server has routes such as `/sessions` (added through `router` object), so you hit the route: `http://localhost:3001/sessions`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register your Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   gameTitle: String,
   users: [],
   scores: [],
   positions: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('session', SessionSchema);
```

And here you need to use the mongo schema model, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());


const SessionSchema  = require('./Session'); // register the mongo model

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Session  = mongoose.model('session');

//Post a session to the database
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    const new_session = {
        gameTitle : req.body.gameTitle,
        users : req.body.user,
        scores : req.body.score,
        positions : req.body.position
    };


    new_session.save((err, saved_session) => {
        if(err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(saved_session);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the module.exports line to the post - it was already in the file though. What's the difference between your second block of code and the way I had it set up?